# Why type definitions in npm are placed into @types namespace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Why type definitions in npm are placed into `@types` namespace which is not related to a concrete organization/user/lib? Why npm libraries haven't types in `@[orgname/username/libname]/types` (under an org/user/project namespace)?

Comment: What about libraries that don't have official type definitions? Or any organisation structure?

Comment: @VLAZ Any organization/user has a personal namespace by default: https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes So organization structure exists by default. Unofficial type definitions can be under another organization namespaces, I don't see contradictions here. Let's assume we are talking about official type definitions.

Comment: @types is a project in its own right just like Express or React etc. As a project it is not feasible to publish their code under multiple separate npm accounts. Note that while Typescript has gained popularity these days it hasn't always been the number 1 choice of programming language that compiles to javascript. For a long time other languages were more popular like Coffeescript, Dart or even plain old javascript (even today there are plenty of developers who prefer javascript to typescript)..

Comment: .. by default npm module names are flat, for example you'd `import React from 'react'` instead of `import React from 'Facebook/react'`. Organisation structure exist to work around module name collision but is not the expected default. The expected default behavior is to publish modules without any organisation namespace (the opposite to Java culture)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the DefinitelyTyped project (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

It's a third party project, with the NPM organization "@types". Its contributors create, maintain, and host type definition files for projects that don't want to write their source code in TypeScript or don't want to publish type definition files themselves.

Comment: Is there any ideas why maintainers of different projects don't want to deliver types out of the box? I see the current way has an issue developer may get obsolete type definitions from DefinitelyTyped. Is there a a way to checkout that type definitions version and lib version are consistent?

Comment: There's technically no guarantee that any type definitions are perfect. Even if a project is written in TypeScript so that the TypeScript compiler could create the type definition files automatically every time they use it to create compiled JavaScript, there could be a bug in the TypeScript compiler causing an issue with the generated type definition files. Using TypeScript means accepting some additional complexity over using just JavaScript. Of course, the TypeScript compiler is probably the best option we have for generating high quality type definition files.

Comment: As for why a project's creators/maintainers may not want to use TypeScript instead of JavaScript for its source code, that's up to them. It's possible to use JavaScript without having written it in TypeScript. Some people just don't see the value you get from it as being worth the cost. They're publishing something free for the world to use, and they have the right to do that any way they like.

Comment: If someone likes their project and thinks it would be even better with types, then they can offer to create and maintain those types, as part of the project itself, if the maintainers are okay with the project taking on that responsibility, or in the DefinitelyTyped project if the project's maintainers would rather another project be responsible for that.

Comment: All libs I was used before were in @types namespace. Could you provide any lib which provides official types out of the box please?

Comment: @pepeevich https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns